# Count number of terminal opened by current user?

Tags: shell

I want to find out number of terminal opened by current user using SHELL SCRIPT.
How to write shell script for that?

Comment: `man who`, `man wc` will give you a good start

Comment: @fedorqui I am new to shell script. I have searched on internet ,but i didn't got proper answer.

Answer (score 1):

`who | grep root | wc -l` replacing `root` with any user will tell you the number of terminals that the specified user has open.